# How to ensure the location of an element is fixed in bootstrap 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a landing page built in Twitter Bootstrap 2.

```
  <section id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
          <h1>We are experts in <span class="underline" id="typer-1">business solutions</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="feature span4">
          <div aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon-tint"></div>
          <h3>Design</h3>
          <p class="hidden-phone">Proin ut quam eros. Donec sed lobortis diam. Nulla nec odio lacus. Quisque porttitor egestas dolor in placerat. Nunc vehicula dapibus ipsum. Duis venenatis risus non nunc fermentum dapibus.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="feature span4">
          <div aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon-code"></div>
          <h3>Development</h3>
          <p class="hidden-phone">Proin ut quam eros. Donec sed lobortis diam. Nulla nec odio lacus. Quisque porttitor egestas dolor in placerat. Nunc vehicula dapibus ipsum. Duis venenatis risus non nunc fermentum dapibus.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="feature span4">
          <div aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon-mobile"></div>
          <h3>Apps</h3>
          <p class="hidden-phone">Proin ut quam eros. Donec sed lobortis diam. Nulla nec odio lacus. Quisque porttitor egestas dolor in placerat. Nunc vehicula dapibus ipsum. Duis venenatis risus non nunc fermentum dapibus.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>   </section>
```

I am using a jQuery plugin [typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/blob/master/README.md) to rotate words to make things prettier, however, unfortunately in this setup it doesn't work as desired.

The problem is, the `h1` blob of text gets moved (re-centered) as soon as `typed.js` changes a character. So the text is really fuzzy and hard to read.

Is there any way to make the position of the `h1` block static, so it does not move when the lenght of its contents changes?

Comment: ...give it a fixed width?

Comment: Sounds like your H1 has text-align:center applied to it? Try changing this to text-align:left

Comment: yes, is it `text-align:center`?

Comment: @SimonMason is it possible to create a special class and add it onto h1 tag in html without overrriding h1's defined behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Using your html, bootstrap 2.3 and [the example from typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/wiki) I couldn't reproduce it in

**[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omq59x4p/)**

```
note: click on the button to start typing
```

There must be something else in your css that causes the repositioning and bluring

EDIT: yup, `text-align: center;` was on the h1, it would recalculate position each time. `text-align: left;` was the fix!

Comment: I found it. `section#about h1` had `text-align: center;`. I changed it to `text-align: left;` I'm sorry for this noobish question, I don't know how css works (yet).